# Comment section after WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT FAILURE throwing error in sqlplus

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

I have encountered a weird scenario. I have a script file which I can run fine from tools like plsql developer, but when I run the file from sqlplsus it gives error. I have found the reason for the same. My doubt is regarding the reason of the 'reason' :)

The reason for the error was in below script. Please note the exact structure of the script -

```
WHENEVER SQLERROR CONTINUE;

--DROP TABLE table3;  
DROP TABLE table1;
DROP TABLE table2;

WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT FAILURE;

/*CREATE TABLE table3  
AS
SELECT DISTINCT col1
FROM table3, table4
WHERE colx = coly' .....
<some more codes> */

CREATE TABLE table1 
AS
SELECT DISTINCT col1
....

CREATE TABLE table2
AS
SELECT DISTINCT col2
....
[THE ORIGINAL CODE]
```

I am receiving error because of the comment section after WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT FAILURE; The error is -

> SP2-0103: Nothing in SQL buffer to run. SP2-0042: unknown command "AS"
>   - rest of line ignored.

When I removed that comment section from the file, the script ran fine from sqlplus.

My question is why the comment section is creating error after the EXIT FAILURE ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your comment is interpreted as / which means "run what is in the buffer". Just add a space after `/*`.

See below what type of comments you can use in sqlplus:

> Syntax:
>
> REMARK Single line comment
>
> -- Single line comment
>
> /* Single line comment */
>
> /*
>
> ```
>  Multi Line
>  comment
> ```
>
> */

> A common mistake is to use /* but not followed by a space (or newline) this will be interpreted as "/" and will execute
> the previous SQL command. Although the actual comment will be ignored
> this behaviour can have significant unexpected results: even if
> there's no previous command to execute then Oracle will error with
> "Nothing in SQL buffer to run".

http://ss64.com/ora/syntax-sqlplus-remark.html

**UPDATE:** Explaining the error:

The "Nothing in SQL buffer to run" error means simply there is nothing in the buffer. Previous commands were executed and purged from buffer. If you have had written `select something`  then hit enter and then slash then in the buffer would be `select something` and had tried to run that.
But now there is nothing in the buffer.

*But why there is the error with `AS`?* Well, the interpreter, after running the line with `/*CREATE...` (the only meaning of the line it was run what's in the buffer) it goes to next line and expects a new command. The command is `AS`. The error is `"unknown command "AS""`, which is correct.

Technically, this is the first error. (you asked for `whenever sqlerror exit`). The empty buffer was not an error but just a message that is nothing to run in the buffer.

Comment: Thanks Florin for your help...much appreciated!! Just some doubts,..1) when interpreter encounters '/', there are 2 "drop"s and 1 "whenever sqlerror" command in buffer, so why is it giving "Nothing in SQL buffer to run"... 2) As I know '/' is the command when the interpreter understands that the sql file has ended and now execute all things in buffer...but it is also giving "unknown command "AS"" error,,,this means it is going forward to the line of "AS"...how is that possible? Am I missing something here ?

Comment: added in the answer some explanations of the error messages.